# Offline database file system using JSON. Using one or multiple files

Tags: database, json, filesystems, offline

I just wanted to hear some opinions about what i am going to do. The case is simple. I need to implement an offline database filesystem using JSON.

The problem i got is whether to use one JSON file to represent all my resources or one JSON for each resource. Assuming that i need to store information about many different files and each file might have some comments; that is, an array of comments and perhaps some extra attributes like name, details, etc.

I could create a JSONobject representing that structure and then when new resource is added, a new JSONojbect will be created representing that resource. Then it would simply appended to one file holding all information for all resources. When i want to access resource 1, i could just query the JSON file and find the resource with id 1. Simple, but when many resources are used, it would be apparently very slow...(implemented in JS) and a bit troublesome to store all information in an array... etc.

The other solution i am thinking, since each resource is a file, i could then represent each file with a JSONobject. Assuming that i now exactly the name of the file, i could just open the file.json and get the information i want.

Do you think this might be a viable solution assuming that i going to use the second method?

Any feedback or alternative ways to do it is appreciated :).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used xml for similar application and found that even very large files weren't too slow however I was using AIR which might be faster than a browser. Since it's local performance isn't that important so I don't think you would see any difference storing all data in one file.
The issue with multiple files would be that you would need to open a file check data and then delete it as opposed to just removing an item from the array. Then there's also the amount of files and difficulty of backup if that's important.

Comment: Well, it will be a NodeJS app so it is possible.

Comment: No prob, you should test in case it is slower in a browser. I an AIR app I remember I got over 200mb of text written in 10 minutes or so (after infinite loop accident). App did consume 100% cpu but never even crashed :)